# Association scoping for new/unsaved records in Rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

In the Rails_admin [wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Associations-scoping), they describe how association scoping can work:

```
config.model Team do
  field :players do
    associated_collection_cache_all false  # REQUIRED if you want to SORT the list as below
    associated_collection_scope do
      # bindings[:object] & bindings[:controller] are available, but not in scope's block!
      team = bindings[:object]
      Proc.new { |scope|
        # scoping all Players currently, let's limit them to the team's league
        # Be sure to limit if there are a lot of Players and order them by position
        scope = scope.where(league_id: team.league_id) if team.present?
        scope = scope.limit(30).reorder('players.position DESC') # REorder, not ORDER
      }
    end
  end
end
```

However, they also mention:

> Also note that the scope takes in to account the saved version of the
>   record, not considering any unsaved changes you may have made in the
>   edit form. If you change the team's league, you'll still see the
>   players from the old league until you save.

What's the best way to make this work for new, unsaved records too? So when I change the league in the form, the players will update accordingly, without having to save the record.

Comment: Did you found answer? I want same functionality.